# Wait on Child Scripts Executed in New Terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I have a parent script that executes three child scripts.  I am trying to 1) open each child script in a new terminal window; and 2) make the parent script **wait** for each child script to exit before continuing.  So:

master

1. child-1 in new terminal
2. (wait for child-1 to exit)
3. child-2 in new terminal
4. (wait for child-2 to exit)
5. child-3 in new terminal
6. (wait for child-3 to exit)

exit

I can make the child scripts open in a new terminal window, but all three child scripts execute in sequence without waiting.  Here's the parent script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# workspace
mkdir ./temp

# system setup
echo "***** setting up system environment *****"
gnome-terminal -x ./setup_sysconfig > setup-system.log
wait

# user setup
echo "***** setting up user environment *****"
gnome-terminal -x ./setup_usrconfig > setup-user.log
wait

# server setup
echo "***** setting up server environment *****"
gnome-terminal -x ./setup_svrconfig > setup-server.log
wait

# cleanup
rm -r ./temp

echo "Initial System Setup Complete"
exit 0
```

How can I get the child scripts to run in a separate terminal while forcing the parent script to wait for each script to finish?  (I'm on Ubuntu 13.04.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wait` will only wait for processes which you have sent to the background to complete. I believe if you use the `--disable-factory` option of `gnome-terminal` then the script will wait for the command to finish:

```
gnome-terminal --disable-factory -x ./setup_svrconfig > setup-server.log
```